# Concatenating in SQL Server 2008 and 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this concatenating function that works fine in SQL Server 2012:

```
declare @reportN nvarchar(255)
set @reportName = concat(year(getdate()), '-',33);

select @reportN
```

Which gives result 2013-33

I also have SQL Server 2008 which doesn't support `concat` function so when I try to do it following way.

```
declare @r nvarchar(255)
set @r = (year(getdate()) + '-' + 33);
select @r
```

I get result of 2046 basically it adds it. Can you let me know how to fix it so I get it result of 2013-33. Thanks

Comment: cast the year to a string `cast(year(getdate()) as varchar(4)) + '-33'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your `year(getDate())` a CHAR (or some other text). You are concatenating it to an integer 33. Since year() returns an INT and you are concatenating to an INT (33) it returns and INT.

```
declare @r nvarchar(255)
set @r=(CONVERT(CHAR(4), year(getdate()))+'-'+'33');
select @r
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just cast the year as a string:

```
  declare @r nvarchar(255)
  set @r= CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS CHAR(4)) +'-33';
  select @r
```

The `CONCAT()` function in 2012 converts all inputs to strings, you need to explicitly do this prior to 2012 if you want to concatenate strings.

Answer (score 0):

Convert 33 to varchar:

```
declare @r nvarchar(255)
      set @r=(convert(varchar(4),year(getdate()))+'-'+'33');
      select @r
```

Comment: year returns an `int` so you will not be able to concatenate a string to it.